# NULL not being counted in aggregate SQL

Tags: sql

Could use a little help with this SQL query.

Let's say I have a table, called StudentGrades, containing a list of students and a flag indicating whether they have passed a class or not. Assuming there are a large portion of students who have not yet been given a grade, how do I calculate the current percentage of those students that have passed/failed or have not been given a grade.

```
ID     LastName         GradeGiven
-------------------------------
1      Bueller          PASS
2      Smith            FAIL
3      Carter           FAIL
4      Howell           NULL
5      Clinton          PASS
6      Brown            FAIL
.
.
.
48     Jones            NULL
49     Frank            NULL
50     Jenkins          NULL
```

I would like to be able create a query that would display the number of students who passed, failed, and don't have a grade assigned yet. To do this I create this query ...

```
SELECT
  COUNT(GradeGiven) AS "Count of each Grade",
  GradeGiven,
  COUNT(GradeGiven * 100.0/(SELECT COUNT(*) from StudentGrades) AS "Percentage"
FROM 
  StudentGrades
GROUP BY 
  GradeGiven
```

My question is that `NULL` shows up as having a count of `0`, even though it is present. Shouldn't it have a count even if it represents no value? I would have expected it to have a count of 45 and a large percentage if most of the grades has not been filled out. Yet it is `0.000`

```
Count        GradeGiven         Percentage
------------------------------------------
0            NULL                 0.000
2            PASS                 4.000
3            FAIL                 6.000
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `count(*)` or `count(1)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Count of each Grade",
       GradeGiven,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0/(SELECT COUNT(*) from StudentGrades) AS "Percentage"
FROM StudentGrades
GROUP BY GradeGiven;
```

Confusion over `count(<column name>)` is why I don't think it should be used, at least by beginners in SQL.  You can read more about my opinion in this matter [here](http://blog.data-miners.com/2014/03/three-sql-constructs-you-can-forget.html).

Comment: That worked great! Thank you. I will check out your link to learn more why `count(<column name>)` was a bad choice.